# How to pass a nullable string to an SP from C#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I have a string property that may or may not be null.

I am passing it to the SP using this call:

```
db.AddInParameter(InsertMessageDetailCommand, "MyParam", System.Data.DbType.String, this.myParam);
```

the field is defined in the SP like this:

```
@MyParam nvarchar(50)
```

How can I change the SP to allow for null values, and if param value is null insert a null into the database table later in the SP?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry - wrong pasted code, let me update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To declare a stored procedure parameter as optional:

```
@MyParam nvarchar(50) = NULL
```

For instance:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc
(
    @Param1 varchar(50) = NULL
)
AS
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    TestTable
WHERE
    ((@Param1 IS NULL) OR (col1 = @Param1))
```

But please be aware that this pattern, when used with many parameters can lead to incorrectly cached query plans due to 'parameter sniffing'.

Comment: @Mitch - IIRC, parameter sniffing is less of an an issue in SQL Server 2005+, and there is also the OPTIMIZE FOR clause when problems do arise - http://blogs.msdn.com/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/31/565991.aspx

Comment: @Russ Cam: thanks, I'm aware of that. I've popsted to SO about OPTIMISE FOR in fact.